# How to fix Unspecified Error trying to programmatically create printer ports?

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I am trying to create 100 printer ports using a csv file that has IPAddress. I am spinning through this file using VB 2008 and then calling a function to create the port. The first port gets created fine but when program gets second address and passes it to function gets an unspecified error.

call to the function
     MakePort("IP_" & ln, ln)

```
Private Function MakePort(ByVal lPrinterName As String, ByVal _      lHostAddress As String)
    Dim res As Boolean = False
    Dim objWMIService As WbemScripting.SWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Dim objNewPort = objWMIService.Get("WIN32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_
    Try
        objNewPort.Name = lPrinterName
        objNewPort.Protocol = 1
        objNewPort.HostAddress = lHostAddress
        objNewPort.PortNumber = "6101"
        objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = False

        objNewPort.Put_()
        res = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        res = False
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    objNewPort.Name = ""
    objNewPort.Protocol = ""
    objNewPort.HostAddress = ""
    objNewPort.PortNumber = ""

    objNewPort = Nothing
    objWMIService = Nothing


    Return res
End Function
```

On the Line   objNewPort.Name = lPrinterName in second pass is where the Unspecified Error occurs.
Looking to save someone time by not having them manually type in the ports

Comment: Have you checked the value of `lPrinterName` to make sure that there are really no disallowed characters in it like spaces?

Comment: Just to double check because I wanted to not think I was better than that, the value of lPrinterName is "IP_192.168.0.201" no extra characters. I really dislike "unspecified error"

Comment: If you remove the lines `objNewPort.Name = ""` through to `objWMIService = Nothing
`, does it work? You don't need those lines, so all they can do is potentially cause problems.

Comment: Also, according to [Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-tcpipprinterport), `objNewPort.PortNumber` should be a UInt32, not a string. Although I don't think that'll make it work.

Comment: I decided to go PowerShell. was able to get it working using

Answer (score 1):

This actually worked for me. Powershell script.

```
$PrinterList=get-content C:\scripts\printers.csv 
FOREACH ($ip in $PrinterList) {   
   Print $I $port=[wmiclass]"Win32_TcpIpPrinterPort" 
   $port.psbase.scope.options.EnablePrivileges=$true 
   $newPort=$port.CreateInstance() 
   $newport.name="$ip" 
   $newport.Protocol=1 
   $newport.HostAddress=$ip 
   $newport.PortNumber="6101" 
   $newport.SnmpEnabled=$false 
   $newport.Put()
}
```